# How to get next data with pagination in Quasar Framework?

Tags: vue.js, datatables, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to use datatable with server pagination in Quasar Framework, I already try the example, but I didn't get it if my Rest API return this kind of JSON,

```
{
"count": 808,
"next": "http://localhost:8000/v1/assets?expand=village.subdistrict.city.province&page=2",
"previous": null,
result: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0, sodium: 87, calcium: '14%', iron: '1%' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9.0, carbs: 37, protein: 4.3, sodium: 129, calcium: '8%', iron: '1%' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, fat: 16.0, carbs: 23, protein: 6.0, sodium: 337, calcium: '6%', iron: '7%' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Cupcake', calories: 305, fat: 3.7, carbs: 67, protein: 4.3, sodium: 413, calcium: '3%', iron: '8%' },
]
}
```

I think the documentation doesn't explain this case
How can I use 'next' to fetch the next page ?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation part you're referring to?

Comment: @DavidGo https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Server-side-pagination%2C-filter-and-sorting this is the doc i refer to, please kindly check it, im stuck

Comment: You have @onRequest event from the table, once you made a call it's up to you what to do with response. As I see it: table gives you this event, which triggers you api call, then if you got `next` from the response, you can trigger your fetch function again, recursevely